# Escape bash special characters inside double quotes

Tags: bash, docker

I'm trying to run the following command from a tutorial:

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/check --network des mongo:4.2 bash -c \
"mongorestore -hmongo -u moAdmin -p <PWD> --gzip --archive=/check/test.gz  --nsInclude='test.*' --drop"
```

The problem is that the password contains ! and | and I'm not sure how to correctly escape these inside the already used double quotes.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You could temporarily turn off history expansion:

```
set +H
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/check --network des mongo:4.2 bash -c \
"mongorestore -hmongo -u moAdmin -p <PWD> --gzip --archive=/check/test.gz  --nsInclude='test.*' --drop"
set -H
```

Or you could just escape the character:

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/check --network des mongo:4.2 bash -c \
"mongorestore -hmongo -u moAdmin -p P@assword\! --gzip --archive=/check/test.gz  --nsInclude='test.*' --drop"
```

You could store it in a variable:

```
password='P@ssword!'
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/check --network des mongo:4.2 bash -c \
"mongorestore -hmongo -u moAdmin -p \"$password\" --gzip --archive=/check/test.gz  --nsInclude='test.*' --drop"
```